# Apply jquery code to multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code which is working but I have a lot of duplication:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp2j/25/

```
$('input.apple').on('keyup', function() {
    $("div.apple").html(this.value);
});

$('input.orange').on('keyup', function() {
    $("div.orange").html(this.value);
});

$('input.banana').on('keyup', function() {
    $("div.banana").html(this.value);
});
```

I was wondering if there is a way to put the items into some sort of array, so that I can have the same code apply to several different fields.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Comment: Why not give them a second common class?

Comment: How about: http://jsfiddle.net/tn5uU/ - targets a common class, then grabs the new `data-fruit` attribute I added

Comment: @Ian +1 that's the better approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can target all inputs, or just give them a common class to target, and extract something, I used the class, but data attributes would be easier if the elements had multiple classes etc :

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.'+this.className).html(this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp2j/26/)

**EDIT:**

as noted above, if the elements have multiple classes, use data attributes :

```
<input class="input" data-id="apple" >
<input class="input" data-id="orange" >
<input class="input" data-id="banana" >
```

JS

```
$('.input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.' + $(this).data('id')).html(this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp2j/28/)

Comment: The problem with this is, what if the `input` has more classes than the `banana`.

Comment: @herby Read the answer: `but data attributes would be easier if the elements had multiple classes etc `. This is just an example

Comment: I guess I can actually post some code for the alternative, rather than just explain it.

Comment: what is this `data-id`? I've not used it.  can you please explain a little?

Comment: @user1671639 It's just an attribute (a valid one) on the element that you can use to store data/info about it. This code then retrieves it later in the event handler, and uses it to find the target output element. It effectively stores the class of the div where its text should be outputted

Comment: @user1671639 - those are [**HTML5 data attributes**](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) !

Comment: @user1671639 that is way to create custome data attributes like `data-yourDataName`

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using the class name:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    $("div." + $(this).attr('class')).html(this.value);
});
```

I would prefer to have the relationship/link in a `data-fruit` attribute, for example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2wDR/1/)

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    $("div[data-fruit=" + $(this).data('fruit') + "]").html(this.value);
});
```

The class name is not really best suited to define the relationship. Consider if some designer is given your code, and starts throwing extra classes in there for styling, this would break the code.

Comment: @Ian yes, was adding a version that uses `data-fruit` instead of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    var clas = $(this).prop('class');
    $("div." + clas).html(this.value);
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp2j/29/)

After checking @Ian's fiddle, I understood my mistake.  Incase if you add class to the `input` then the above will fail beacuse it takes the whole attribute.

As adeneo suggested, try to use **HTML5 data attributes**.

I'hv update it [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp2j/31/).

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the fiddle.  Found the difference and got the reason of using `data` attribute.