# what's data-reactid attribute in html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

While I was going through the HTML of some pages, I noticed that some of them use this attribute "data-reactid" like :

```
 <a data-reactid="......" ></a>
```

What is that attribute and what is its function ?

Comment: `data-reactid` is custom attribute used by [React JavaScript library](http://facebook.github.io/react/). Which is developed to use with Facebook & Instagram.

Comment: Please note that all the answers are explaining what custom date- attributes are and not explaining what data-reactid is. It is used by react to be able to reference the dom object with the react element class instance.

Comment: @adrianj98, why didn't you post your comment as an answer instead?

Comment: Wonder, if Facebook uses React why I don't find any data-reactid in their site?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The `data-reactid` attribute is a custom attribute used so that [React](https://facebook.github.io/react) can uniquely identify its components within the DOM.

This is important because React applications can be [rendered at the server](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver) as well as the client. Internally React builds up a representation of references to the DOM nodes that make up your application (simplified version is below).

```
{
  id: '.1oqi7occu80',
  node: DivRef,
  children: [
    {
      id: '.1oqi7occu80.0',
      node: SpanRef,
      children: [
        {
          id: '.1oqi7occu80.0.0',
          node: InputRef,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There's no way to share the actual object references between the server and the client and sending a serialized version of the entire component tree is potentially expensive. When the application is rendered at the server and React is loaded at the client, the only data it has are the `data-reactid` attributes.

```
<div data-reactid='.loqi70ccu80'>
  <span data-reactid='.loqi70ccu80.0'>
    <input data-reactid='.loqi70ccu80.0' />
  </span>
</div>
```

It needs to be able to convert that back into the data structure above. The way it does that is with the unique `data-reactid` attributes. This is called *inflating* the component tree.

You might also notice that if React renders at the client-side, it uses the `data-reactid` attribute, even though it doesn't need to lose its references. In some browsers, it inserts your application into the DOM using `.innerHTML` then it inflates the component tree straight away, as a performance boost.

The other interesting difference is that client-side rendered React ids will have an incremental integer format (like `.0.1.4.3`), whereas server-rendered ones will be prefixed with a random string (such as `.loqi70ccu80.1.4.3`). This is because the application might be rendered across multiple servers and it's important that there are no collisions. At the client-side, there is only one rendering process, which means counters can be used to ensure unique ids.

[**React 15** uses `document.createElement` instead](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/03/07/react-v15-rc1.html#document.createelement-is-in-and-data-reactid-is-out), so client rendered markup won't include these attributes anymore.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's the only one that answers the question.

Comment: https://gcanti.github.io/2014/11/24/understanding-react-and-reimplementing-it-from-scratch-part-2.html

Comment: for React v15+: > data-reactid is still present for server-rendered content, however it is much smaller than before and is simply an auto-incrementing counter.

Comment: @RationalDev Ah, that's interesting. How does it get round the collision problem if the app is rendered on multiple servers?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was trying to figure out why I was getting, eg: data-reactid="1" with React 15.1.0, but it was because I was pre-rendering a "static" page. Relevant commit seems to be here: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5205/commits/e48c8be556fd0ef8edee76a1d0c0c686880d9c65

Comment: i was looking for that last section, thanks for adding that. I was confused why my client markup didn't include it like it did before, but another part of my app did have it (it was rendered on the server).

Answer (score 35):

It's a custom html attribute but probably in this case is used by the Facebook React JS Library.

Take a look: http://facebook.github.io/react/

Answer (score 11):

[**Custom Data attribute**](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) in HTML5

**Would like to quote Ian's comment in my answer:**

> It's just an attribute (a valid one) on the element that you can use
>   to store data/info about it.
>
> This code then retrieves it later in the event handler, and uses it to
>   find the target output element. It effectively stores the class of the
>   div where its text should be outputted.

`reactid` is just a suffix, you can have any name here eg: `data-Ayman`.

If you want to find the difference check the fiddles in this [SO answer and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17573494/1671639).

Comment: note that you can't use uppercase letters in the attribute name, according to the link you supplied.

Comment: Yeah, that restriction is a bit misleading. The actual attribute name, in the DOM itself, can't have uppercase letters, but the attribute as written out in the HTML tag can, because all tag and attribute names are automatically lowercased as they're read anyway. So in HTML you can use uppercase letters, but in JS it'll all end up lowercase. https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Answer (score 3):

data attributes are commonly used for a variety of interactions. Typically via javascript. They do not affect anything regarding site behavior and stand as a convenient method to pass data for whatever purpose needed. Here is an article that may clear things up:

http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

You can create a data attribute by prefixing `data-` to any standard attribute safe string (alphanumeric with no spaces or special characters). For example, `data-id` or in this case `data-reactid`

Answer (score 3):

That's the HTML data attribute.
See this for more detail: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Basically it's just a container of your custom data while still making the HTML valid.
It's `data-` plus some unique identifier.