# MSXML2.XMLHTTP GetElementsbyTagName no longer working on webpage

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbytagname

The following code has been working for the past 140 days, but 5 days ago it stopped.  The code (poorly written "raccoon style") scrapes daily option sheets from yahoo finance.  I have an array of stock symbols that are fed one by one into yahoo.  The first web request pulls up the initial option page, which is turned into an htmlfile.  I pull the option expiration dates out of the htmlfile using getElementsByTagName("select") and creating an object.  If object.Item.childNodes.Length<>0 then it loads the childnode values into an array which is then used to create the URL to pull the monthly expirations option sheets.

When I open the webpage with inspect element (Chrome) the

```
Sub HTML_Table_To_Excel()
        Dim htm As Object, temp As Variant, r As Long, s As Variant, t As Long, vDate As Variant, d As Long, ldate As Long, web_url As String
        Dim obTable As Object, aitemp() As Variant, aiExpDates() As String, lTab As Long, start As Long, sstop As Long, elapsed As Long, z As Long, vwebpage As Object
        Dim html_content As Object, lmatch As Long, http As Object, e As Long, hits As Long
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ReDim aiExpDates(11)
        aiExpDates() = Create12ExpirationDates()
        start = Timer
        hits = 0
        temp = [Symbol].Value


        'LBound(temp, 1)
        For r = LBound(temp, 1) To UBound(temp, 1)

         ReDim aitemp(10, 0)
         z = 0
       d = 0
       e = 0
        web_url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & temp(r, 1) & "/options?p=" & temp(r, 1)

        'Create HTMLFile Object
        Set html_content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

            'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
        Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        With http
            .Open "GET", web_url, False
            .Send
    '         While Not .readyState = 4
     '           Sleep (500)
      '      Wend

            html_content.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText


        End With
checkpageload:
    hits = hits + 1

            On Error Resume Next
            Set vwebpage = html_content.getElementsByTagName("select")
            If vwebpage.Item.ChildNodes.Length = 0 Then
            Set html_content = Nothing
         Set http = Nothing
         Set html_content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
            With http
            .Open "GET", web_url, False
            .Send
    '         While Not .readyState = 4
     '           Sleep (500)
      '      Wend
            html_content.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
            End With
           d = d + 1
                 If d = 10 Then
                GoTo continue
                End If
            GoTo checkpageload
            End If
            hits = hits + 1
            ReDim vDate(vwebpage.Item.ChildNodes.Length - 1)
            For Each obTable In vwebpage.Item.ChildNodes
              lmatch = 0

            lmatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(obTable.Value, aiExpDates(), 0)
                If lmatch <> 0 Then
                    vDate(z) = obTable.Value
                    z = z + 1
                End If

            Next obTable
            ReDim Preserve vDate(z - 1)
            z = 0
            On Error GoTo 0
      For ldate = LBound(vDate) To UBound(vDate)
        web_url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & temp(r, 1) & "/options?p=" & temp(r, 1) & "&date=" & vDate(ldate)
     hits = hits + 1
        'Create HTMLFile Object
        Set html_content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
     With http
            .Open "GET", web_url, False
            .Send
    '         While Not .readyState = 4
     '           Sleep (500)
      '      Wend
            html_content.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
     End With

test:
        If html_content.getElementsByTagName("tbody").Length < 2 Then
       ' MsgBox "the page did not load"
         Set html_content = Nothing
         Set http = Nothing
         Set html_content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        With http
            .Open "GET", web_url, False
            .Send
    '         While Not .readyState = 4                               '<---------- wait
     '           Sleep (500)
      '      Wend
            html_content.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
        End With
        d = d + 1
        If d = 10 Then
            GoTo continue
           End If
        GoTo test

           End If
       Set obTable = html_content.getElementsByTagName("tbody")



      For s = 0 To obTable(1).Rows.Length - 1
      For t = 0 To obTable(1).Rows(0).Cells.Length - 1

       aitemp(t, e) = obTable(1).Rows(s).Cells(t).innerText

        Next t
        aitemp(10, e) = Date - 1

        e = e + 1
        ReDim Preserve aitemp(UBound(aitemp, 1), UBound(aitemp, 2) + 1)
    Next s

    If obTable.Length = 3 Then
         s = 0: t = 0
        For s = 0 To obTable(2).Rows.Length - 1
        For t = 0 To obTable(2).Rows(0).Cells.Length - 1

       aitemp(t, e) = obTable(2).Rows(s).Cells(t).innerText

        Next t
        aitemp(10, e) = Date - 1
        e = e + 1
        ReDim Preserve aitemp(UBound(aitemp, 1), UBound(aitemp, 2) + 1)
    Next s
    End If


    Next ldate
    ReDim Preserve aitemp(UBound(aitemp, 1), UBound(aitemp, 2) - 1)

    Worksheets(temp(r, 1)).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Resize(UBound(aitemp, 2), UBound(aitemp, 1) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(aitemp)
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
continue:
    Next r
    ThisWorkbook.Save
     sstop = Timer
     elapsed = (sstop - start) / 60
        MsgBox elapsed & vbCr & " # of Resubmittals " & d & vbCr & "webhits = " & hits

    End Sub
```

Comment: I can't copy this into a module because of the poor formatting.  So passing on this until formatting fixed.

Comment: I understand.  I was able to find the TagName <Select> when using an instance of Internet Explorer but when I used xmlhttprequest the TagName <Select> was not present.  I could use this IE method but it is so slow.

Comment: EDITED: I have added tabs to code block because VBA labels don't indent in VBA IDE.    Still does not compile because of Create12ExpirationDates() not given.

Comment: Also [Symbol] looks like a defined named range.  You need to tell us the contents of a range defined as Symbol.  Please open a new workbook and copy over as much as is required to get it to compile.

Comment: OK, I can see that the HTML is different when in a browser and when using XHR.  This suggests the page is created dynamically.  Indeed one can see in the HTML the attribute data-reactid on the nodes which indicates it is written using React.js.  See SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585787/whats-data-reactid-attribute-in-html