# Why would data-reactid attributes be visible in the DOM one day and not the next?

Tags: reactjs, developer-console

Yesterday I inspected a 3rd party app (tuning my Chrome Extension to work with it) and saw a button with the following:

```
<button type="button" role="button" tabindex="0" class="_3Zltvf_ _3C6pvc5 _3uisJCE _2T9m9MZ _13mEBGY _3UROOwf _31TNahl" style="margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;cursor:pointer;" data-reactid=".4.0.1:1.0:$_6101.2.1.0"><span class="QJpaM9j" data-reactid=".4.0.1:1.0:$_6101.2.1.0.0"><span class="_1O6_bJL" data-reactid=".4.0.1:1.0:$_6101.2.1.0.0.0"><svg name="IconFeedback" viewBox="0 0 1920 1920" width="1em" height="1em" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" class="rDcS_u2 _1-0JnEU _17OBplh _35T0lCf" data-reactid=".4.0.1:1.0:$_6101.2.1.0.0.0.0"><g role="presentation" data-reactid=".4.0.1:1.0:$_6101.2.1.0.0.0.0.2"><path d="M84 0v1423.143h437.875V1920l621.235-496.857h692.39V0H84zm109.469 109.464H1726.03V1313.57h-621.235l-473.452 378.746v-378.746H193.469V109.464z" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" data-reactid=".4.0.1:1.0:$_6101.2.1.0.0.0.0.2.0"></path></g></svg></span><span class="_3fbL2UF" data-reactid=".4.0.1:1.0:$_6101.2.1.0.0.1">Additional Comments</span></span></button>
```

Today, when I look at the same page, I see:

```
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="OZcxN3v _38BfRnZ _3ZrpMh_ _2Gd45JB _1S_fBD0 Av63EXQ _3RPGyP5" style="margin: 0px 0.5rem 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;"><span class="_33JKgGX"><span class="bvpHuVL"><svg name="IconFeedback" viewBox="0 0 1920 1920" rotate="0" width="1em" height="1em" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" focusable="false" class="_1tTc425 B3Kp9mC _2D8C4d8 _2XRgUDk"><g role="presentation"><path d="M84 0v1423.143h437.875V1920l621.235-496.857h692.39V0H84zm109.469 109.464H1726.03V1313.57h-621.235l-473.452 378.746v-378.746H193.469V109.464z" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"></path></g></svg></span><span class="_3kvuamb">Additional Comments</span></span></button>
```

The data-reactid info is gone...

What determines whether react details show up in the DOM for inspection? I was hoping to use the IDs for processing...
Is there some setting in Developer console?

Using Chrome. Any direction/help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably 3rd party app got a new react version which doesn't use `data-reactid` anymore.

See [what's data-reactid attribute in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585787/whats-data-reactid-attribute-in-html)