# How do I grab with Simple HTML DOM a value within a span that has data-reactid?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Im trying to grab the value from a span that uses data-reactid. It looks like this:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)" data-reactid="36">-0.24 (-0.49%)</span>
```

How would I do that with Simple HTML DOM ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried this. $data = $xpath->find("span[@data-reactid='36'");

Comment: You can refer to this answer
[SIMILAR ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585787/whats-data-reactid-attribute-in-html)

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585787/whats-data-reactid-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 0):

As described in docs (section [How to find HTML elements?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)), you can use `[attribute-name=value]` selector to find elements using their attributes:

```
// Assuming you have already included simple_html_dom.php
$str = '<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)" data-reactid="36">-0.24 (-0.49%)</span>';
$h = str_get_html($str);
print($h->find('[data-reactid=36]', 0)->plaintext);
// Output: -0.24 (-0.49%)
```