# Why is there a ".$" before the key when I transform the children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to get a list of keys of children in my component.  To do that I do the following

```
const keys = React.Children
  .map(children, (child) => child.key)
```

However, now I ant to filter it by a prop so I do the following

```
const activeChildren = React.Children
  .map(children, (child) => child)
  .filter(child => child.props.shown ?? true);
const keys = activeChildren 
  .map((child) => child.key)
```

But the keys I get have a `.$` prefix for some odd reason.  When I do the following I already see the `.$` prefix before each key.

```
const activeChildren = React.Children
  .map(children, (child) => child)
  .map((child) => child.key)
```

I can sort of do a cleanup to remove the prefix, but I was wondering why is even appearing?

For now I've been doing this hack

```
.map(child => child.key.toString().replace('.$', ''));
```

Comment: I haven't messed with any of this, but, could you be running into what occurs when you use [React.Children.toArray](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray), in that the keys get prefixed "to preserve the semantics of nested arrays?" your first map in the second example is effectively just another way of doing a `React.Children.toArray(children)`.

Comment: If it only occurs when you map directly to the child, what you *could* do is map like your first, but return something else for children that don't match your condition, then filter out that something else. that's kinda ugly, similar to using replace... but it won't rely on the prefix always being `.$`. I'd rather someone who knows more about this provide an *actual* answer

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There may be a better solution.

Comment: Also... [in the src](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cae635054e17a6f107a39d328649137b83f25972/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js), .toArray is simply `React.Children.map(children, (child) => child)`, so that does explain the behavior

Comment: Looks like an internal implementation detail. According to the comments in the source code, the `$` is used so that the key is a valid "reactid", which presumably cannot start with a digit.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cae635054e17a6f107a39d328649137b83f25972/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js#L31

Comment: @Andy something related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050789/how-do-you-add-a-custom-attribute-for-children-of-a-react-component-in-typescr

Comment: @HåkenLid that may explain the `$` but not the `.`

Comment: Also an implementation detail: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cae635054e17a6f107a39d328649137b83f25972/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js#L112

Comment: In earlier versions of react, server rendering used to add `data-reactid=".keyname"` all over the html output. But that was changed years ago. This might be some residual artifact of that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585787/whats-data-reactid-attribute-in-html