# How do you add a "custom" attribute for children of a React component in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that generates a TOC and List for the children.  The children are just any JSX.Element.  So this works...

```
<SectionScrollList>
  <View key="first"/>
  <View key="second"/>
  <View key="third"/>
</SectionScrollList>
```

What I would want is to allow the one using SectionScrollList to add a special prop that I would use called `shown` e.g.

```
<SectionScrollList>
  <View key="first" shown={true}/>
  <View key="second" shown={false}/>
  <View key="third" shown={true}/>
</SectionScrollList>
```

but `shown` is not part of `View` is there a way around this aside from

```
<SectionScrollList>
  {shown1 && (<View key="first" />)}
  {shown2 && (<View key="second" />)}
  {shown3 && (<View key="third" />)}
</SectionScrollList>
```

UPDATE: Just to be specific since I saw the answers... I am not looking for how to do the filter implementation, which I know I can simply do `child.props.shown`, but I am looking for the *TypeScript* typing so that it will allow `shown` to be added **ONLY** for children of `SectionScrollList` because I know in Typescript you can simply add `shown` as an Intrinsic attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your update. You can ignore my edits then, they basically explain how you can add the intrinsic attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach to this is to use the React.Children utility provided by React. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren for more info.

For example,

```
const SectionScrollList = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "40px" }}>
      {children &&
        React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
          child.props.shown
            ? React.cloneElement(child, { ...child.props })
            : null
        )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

See codesandbox link for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sutherland-x8i8i

**EDIT**

> This does not answer my question on the types

Well, you can create a type declaration file react.d.ts and add the prop you want in the appropriate interface.

An alternative solution is to create a CustomView component that takes all the props of the in-built View and also the shown prop. Then you can use this in all the child components of SectionScrollList.

See this codesandbox for both solutions https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-sun-u5tp4

NOTE: The sandbox doesn't pick the *shown* prop in the first solution for obvious reasons but it works in a proper IDE like VSCode.

Comment: This does not answer my question on the types.  I know I can access the `prop.shown` for the filter but I want it to pass tsc

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check the new solution that addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var props = { requiredProp: "bar" };
<foo {...props} />; // ok
var badProps = {};
<foo {...badProps} />; // error
```

I believe this is what you are looking for...

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the `children` inside `SectionScrollList` to only show children where `shown === true`.

So basically:

```js
function SectionScrollList(props) {
    let children = React.Children
                     .toArray(props.children)
                     .filter(child => child.props.shown === true)
    // do other things
    return children
}
```

[React.Children.toArray](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray)

Comment: this does not answer my question on how do I fix the Typescript typings.